# Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "BVLinearGradient" was not found in the UIManager

Tags: react-native

the error above is shown in this import

```
        import React from 'react';
import { 
    View, 
    Text, 
    TouchableOpacity, 
    Dimensions,
    StyleSheet,
    StatusBar,
    Image
} from 'react-native';
import * as Animatable from 'react-native-animatable';
import LinearGradient from 'react-native-linear-gradient';
import MaterialIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';
import { useTheme } from '@react-navigation/native';
```

this is the import statement bringing the error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

1. For iOS

   - `cd ios`
   - `pod install`
   - rebuild project
2. For Android:

   - Uninstall application in Android emulator
   - `cd Android`
   - `./gradlew clean && ./gradlew cleanBuildCache`
   - `npm run android`

Answer (score 0):

It worked but first, I need to upgrade my Java version.
Thanks.